# Inserting a string into a list only using the append method

Tags: python, append

I'm struggling with a question at the moment and was wondering if someone could point out and show me where I'm going wrong. I need to insert a string into a list only using the append method at a designated position specified by an insert_position. Here is my code:

```
str1_list = ['one', 'three', 'four']

def insert_value(my_list, value, insert_position):

       new_list = []
       for i in range(len(my_list)):
             if i < insert_position:
                 new_list.append(my_list[i])
             elif i == insert_position:
                 new_list.append(my_list[i])
             else:
                 new_list.append(my_list[i-1])

       return new_list

print(str1_list, 'two', 1)
```

Output should be:

['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

I know the value parameter needs to be somewhere but can't figure out where. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code manually? Also, consider: how many times do you expect the loop to run, and how many times does `.append` need to be called on `new_list`?

Comment: Your code doesn't call "insert_value".

Comment: Do you really need to use the `.append` method ? Anything else is accepted ? no methods in view at all ?

Answer (score 2):

You have a few errors (not using the `value` passed to the function, not caling the function, unneccesary condition). Compare you code with this:

```
str1_list = ['one', 'three', 'four']
def insert_value(my_list, value, insert_position):
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        if i == insert_position:
            new_list.append(value)
        new_list.append(my_list[i])
    return new_list
print(insert_value(str1_list, 'two', 1))
```

Output:

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

Comment: I see where I have gone wrong. I needed to first append the value and then insert it at the index of i. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could just add the new value with the `slice` like,

```
>>> def insert_value(l, value, pos):
...     l[pos:pos] = [value]
...     return l # return is not required, since you want to modify the list ?
... 
>>> l = ['one', 'three', 'four']
>>> insert_value(l, 'two', 1)
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
>>> l
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```